# How do i set up a bearer token in postman from an environment variable?

Tags: postman, postman-collection-runner

I have set up a collection in PostMan and am able to save my bearer token value to an environment variable successfully using the following test

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
pm.environment.set("mytoken", jsonData.token);
```

but how do I set up a new call to use it?

I have tried adding a Header with

```
Authorization Bearer <mytoken>
```

but when I Post the Status is 401 Unauthorized

Comment: Hey, You can also now just use `pm.response.json()` instead of `JSON.parse(responseBody)`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the headers I needed to use

for the key

```
Authorization
```

for the value

```
Bearer {{mytoken}}
```

Comment: I missed answering this question back when I asked it. So just ticket  it now. Other answers here may be better.

Answer (score 19):

You can use `Tests` tab to write your code which updates the Environment variable, as explained in this [link](https://blog.getpostman.com/2014/01/27/extracting-data-from-responses-and-chaining-requests/). Read more about Test scripts [here](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-scripts/).

[image]

Assuming the response of the auth call is:

```
{
    "token": "woaejrlajfaoidhfalskdjfalsdijfasd"
}
```

Then, in `Tests` tab, you can write like:

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);
postman.setEnvironmentVariable("token", jsonData.token);
```

This will update the variable `token` whenever you trigger the auth call. This `token` variable should be used in headers of all the API calls, to update automatically.

Do also check [inheriting the auth](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending-api-requests/authorization/#inheriting-auth).

Comment: Note that `postman.setEnvironmentVariable` [is deprecated](https://learning.postman.com/docs/postman/scripts/test-examples/), for me it did not work at all with the latest Postman v7.18.0.
Use `pm.environment.set` instead.

Answer (score 7):

**Summary:**

1. Create a variable to store Auth Token value in single place to use throughout your collection.
2. Set default method for Authorization for your entire collection.
3. Instead of setting the Authorization header for each request set the Authorization on each request to use "Inherit auth from parent" to automatically populate the request with the proper auth headers.

You can define variables in Postman environments and collections in order to simplify your requests by setting a value in one place and reference it in as many places as necessary. So you can create a variable for your Bearer Token value. Do this by editing your collection and going to the Variables tab to add a new variable.

[image: While editing your collection go to the Variables tab to add a new variable you can use throughout your collection.]

Also while editing your collection go the Authorization tab to set a default authorization for all requests within your collection. You can set the Authorization Type for your collection to Bearer and set the Token value to be your defined variable. This will allow you to use the same authorization token for all of your requests within your collection:

[image: Also while editing your collection go the Authorization tab to set a default authorization for all requests within your collection.]

Then in order to use the collection's default method of authorization, you will need to set the requests within that collection to set the Authorization Type to "Inherit auth from parent". Doing this will allow you to not have to deal with adding the Authorization header manually on to each request. Each request within the collection with the "Inherit auth from parent" authorization type selected will automatically populate the request with the proper headers for authorization if you have defined a default option for the collection like in the previous image.

[image: Set each request to use the Authorization Type "Inherit auth from parent".]

***Cheers!***

Answer (score 7):

I use a script after login post into tests tab like below;

```
let jsonData = JSON.parse(responseBody);

pm.collectionVariables.set("jwt_token", jsonData.data.token);
```

[image]

and create a collection variable like following;
[image]

Answer (score 2):

```
pm.environment.set("JWT",pm.response.json().token)
```

**Note** : `JWT` is the environment variable you set in your environment

Answer (score 1):

Like the way Kristen, said. Or else download latest postman desktop application, in that in authorization they have an option to add bearer token in the header